# How to auto point back the Image when i had capture an image and save on album?

Tags: ios, image, camera

i had done a camera function and trying to make a photo edit after capture image. but the problem is when i run the photo edit, the process is very slow, because the picture is not yet exist on the album. so i try to save the image to photo album after i capture the image. but now how i can point back the same image from the photo album without let the user do any selection on photo album? means after capture and save the image, how i can use coding auto call back the image to direct move to editing? i using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum for saving the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving that captured image in Photo album before edit why not you save it in Document folder of application. To edit the photo take it from document folder and then save that edited photo into photo album. If you want to get that photo from photo album then you have to show image picker controller for same. So i suggest save it in Document folder. Also getting photo from Document folder is faster.

```
 - (IBAction)saveImage 
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
        UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
    }

    - (IBAction)getImage {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    }
```

To remove the image

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:cImagePath error:nil];
```

cImagePath will be the path of image

Comment: i just base on instagram method(i saw it exist after move to editing scene). is that possible show me how to save on document and call back the image? thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi you get the solution

Comment: ya, it works. but had something not sure, checking how to remove the draft image on document after finish edit.

Comment: thanks for your helping. but now still looking how to remove the file.